# to increase the quality code base

Tags: idiomatic-language, terminology

Is it idiomatic to say "to increase the quality of code base"? Like for example in the following sentence:

> The refactoring increased the quality of the project’s code base.

Comment: Hi. The purpose of this site isn't to check people's work. Asking people "is there anything wrong with this" or "does this sound alright/natural/idiomatic" is effectively asking for proofreading. If there's something in particular that makes you unsure about this sentence, please edit your question to say what that is.

Comment: OK, I've modified my question to be specific.

Comment: It may be idiomatic, but it's very vague.  You've essentially said, "refactoring made the project better," but in a less straightforward way.

Comment: I want this sentence to be quite formal because it's to be put in my resume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That is completely normal, and you will see it in technical documents a fair amount. It's maddeningly non-specific, but entirely expected. If you are going to interviews, be prepared for them to ask *in what way* it improved the quality. Was it more readable? Less redundant code? More type-safe?

The linguistic reasons that it's fine is that **quality** is a property that can be **increased**, and you have **specified fully what you increased the quality of**. It's not the simplest sentence structure, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: And if the description is non-specific, perhaps it might as well be "the code base was refactored," since no one would interpret this to mean "I refactored the code and made it worse." But this is getting to be a discussion about how to write a resume, which might be a better fit for the Workplace site.

Comment: You do sometimes refactor for more specific reasons than general improvements. For example, to make it compatible with a particular development tool or code analyser.

Comment: Sure, but those specific reasons might be included in the phrase "increased code quality" (assuming that using the code analyzer was intended to make the code better, not just for fun).  My point was only that if you say "I refactored to improve the code" you might as well say, "I refactored." A statement like yours (refactored for these specific reasons) would be much more compelling.

Comment: Quite often, in my experience, general elements of code quality can suffer when you rearrange to fit a code analyser or a tool. You just hope it's worth it on balance, or they whoever insisted on doing it learns their lesson.